# Dart Flutter How to initialize a class method inside of its class?

Tags: flutter, dart, methods

Here is my class:

```
class WorldTimeClass {
  String flag;
  String url;
  String time;
  String location;

  WorldTimeClass({this.flag, this.url, this.time, this.location});

  Future<String> getData() async {
    try{
      Response load = await get('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$url');
    Map x(){if(load.statusCode == 200){
      print(load.statusCode);

    Map map = jsonDecode(load.body);
    return map;}
    else{
      print('No Access');
      return {1:'NoAccess.'};}
   }
    Map myMap = x();
    String datetime = myMap['utc_datetime'];
    String offsetUTC = myMap['utc_offset'];
    DateTime dateTimeObjectConvert = DateTime.parse(datetime);
    // Below converts the datetime string to a DateTime Object and then converts the UTC Offset to a substring only '01' out of +01:00 and then converts it to an int Object and then adds it to the DateTime Object as a Duration (hours);
    dateTimeObjectConvert = dateTimeObjectConvert.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offsetUTC.substring(1,3))));
    return time = dateTimeObjectConvert.toString();
    }
    catch(e,s){
      return 'Could not access time data from API.\nWe are sorry, please try again.\nError occured: $e';
    }
    

  }
  var myString = getData().then((value) => value);
  DateFormat pretty = DateFormat().add_jm().format(myString);
}
```

How can I access `myString` and execute it inside my class in order to use the resulting `String` object to use it inside a second method `pretty` ?
Also, I need to understand what does the below exception mean?
`Only static members can be accessed in initializers.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Only static members can be accessed in initializers.

This basically means that you cannot call methods of a class or access properties of a specific class directly under class declaration.

You are getting the error on those two lines:

```
  var myString = getData().then((value) => value);
  DateFormat pretty = DateFormat().add_jm().format(myString);
```

Therefore create a method that returns a `String` then all you have to do is to call that method and it will give you the String, and add the code above inside the method:

```
String getDateFormat(){
   var myString = getData().then((value) => value);
  return DateFormat().add_jm().format(myString);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer and solution, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To access your `myString` variable you'll have to do one of those things:

1. Instantiate an `WorldTimeClass` object and access it using `yourWorldClassObject.myString`
2. Make it into in `static` member by using the `static keyword` like `static var myString`. This is what " `Only static members can be accessed in initializers.` " is all about. You have to create an instance of the class if you want to access it's properties, or make them `static` to access them without the need to instantiate an object. Simply `WorldTimeClass.myString`.

Comment: Thank you for the concise and clear explanation Pedro @pedropimont